# Register mutation, is it a CPU hardware issue or a software issue

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, cpu-architecture, arm64, crash-dumps

my android system run monkey，A very strange bug,Register mutation, is it a CPU hardware issue or a software issue?

console log:
-(3)[860:] Unable to handle kernel read from unreadable memory at virtual address 0000000000000010

crash tools backtrace

```
crash> bt
PID: 860    TASK: ffffff802d9b8000  CPU: 3   COMMAND: "android.anim"
 #0 [ffffffc01001b9c0] crash_kexec at ffffffc010372e2c
 #1 [ffffffc01001ba30] die at ffffffc01024766c
 #2 [ffffffc01001ba70] die_kernel_fault at ffffffc01025f0b4
 #3 [ffffffc01001baa0] __do_kernel_fault at ffffffc01025f034
 #4 [ffffffc01001bad0] do_page_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8d2c
 #5 [ffffffc01001bb30] do_translation_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8c84
 #6 [ffffffc01001bb40] do_mem_abort at ffffffc010081638
 #7 [ffffffc01001bcb0] el1_ia at ffffffc010083c40
     PC: ffffffc01030a3cc  [cpuacct_account_field+48]
     LR: ffffffc01030a3c0  [cpuacct_account_field+36]
     SP: ffffffc01001bcc0  PSTATE: 80400085
    X29: ffffffc01001bcc0  X28: 0000000000000001  X27: ffffff80dc5e8c80
    X26: ffffffc010ff6590  X25: ffffff80aaf4d940  X24: ffffff802d9b8000
    X23: 0000000000000000  X22: 0000000000000000  X21: ffffff802d9b8000
    X20: 0000000000000002  X19: 00000000003c0008  X18: ffffffc01001d060
    X17: 000000000005bde0  X16: 000000000000a000  X15: ffffffc00bac6000
    X14: ffffffc00bac32e0  X13: ffffffc00bac32e0  X12: 0000000000000432
    X11: 0000000000000432  X10: 000004c10369e3ba   X9: ffffffc011cb0cc0
     X8: 0000000000000000   X7: 79726f6d656d2072   X6: ffffff80d8400eaf
     X5: 0000000000000003   X4: 0000000000000080   X3: 0000000000000001
     X2: 00000000003c0008   X1: 0000000000000002   X0: ffffff802d9b8000
 #8 [ffffffc01001bcc0] cpuacct_account_field at ffffffc01030a3c8
 #9 [ffffffc01001bcf0] account_system_index_time at ffffffc0102eb260
#10 [ffffffc01001bd40] irqtime_account_process_tick at ffffffc0102eb8d0
#11 [ffffffc01001bda0] account_process_tick at ffffffc0102eb5c4
#12 [ffffffc01001bdc0] update_process_times at ffffffc010346384
#13 [ffffffc01001bdf0] tick_sched_timer$2e93e54c57d54c141bd5e65a4951d56c at ffffffc01035d4c8
#14 [ffffffc01001be20] __run_hrtimer at ffffffc01034a508
#15 [ffffffc01001beb0] hrtimer_interrupt at ffffffc010349070
#16 [ffffffc01001bf20] arch_timer_handler_phys$46ba900623fca114e70958b64dec54b9 at ffffffc010b6eb78
#17 [ffffffc01001bf40] handle_percpu_devid_irq at ffffffc010326828
#18 [ffffffc01001bfa0] __handle_domain_irq at ffffffc01031e594
#19 [ffffffc01001bfe0] gic_handle_irq at ffffffc010081108
--- <IRQ stack> ---
#20 [ffffffc01abdb7e0] el1_irq at ffffffc010083fc0
     PC: ffffffc01031b364  [console_unlock+904]
     LR: ffffffc01031b360  [console_unlock+900]
     SP: ffffffc01abdb7f0  PSTATE: 20400005
    X29: ffffffc01abdb820  X28: 000000000000008d  X27: 0000000000000000
    X26: ffffffc010ffb508  X25: ffffffc011cb2708  X24: ffffffc011cb2618
    X23: ffffffc011e54000  X22: 0000000000000000  X21: ffffffc011e54000
    X20: ffffffc011e54000  X19: 0000000000000000  X18: ffffffc017fc9080
    X17: 000000000005bde0  X16: 00000000000000c0  X15: ffffffc010fc3bd8
    X14: 3030303030303030  X13: 0000000000f2e3f2  X12: 0000000000000000
    X11: 0000000000000000  X10: 00000000ffffffff   X9: 0000000100000001
     X8: 0000000100000001   X7: 79726f6d656d2072   X6: ffffff80d8400eaf
     X5: 0000000000000003   X4: 0000000000000007   X3: 000000000000008d
     X2: 0000000000000000   X1: 0000000000000000   X0: ffffffc011cb2708
#21 [ffffffc01abdb820] console_unlock at ffffffc01031b360
#22 [ffffffc01abdb8b0] vprintk_emit at ffffffc01031af18
#23 [ffffffc01abdb940] vprintk_default at ffffffc01031b714
#24 [ffffffc01abdb9a0] vprintk_func at ffffffc01031e078
#25 [ffffffc01abdba60] printk at ffffffc010319da4
#26 [ffffffc01abdba70] die_kernel_fault at ffffffc01025f090
#27 [ffffffc01abdbaa0] do_page_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8eb4
#28 [ffffffc01abdbb00] do_translation_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8c84
#29 [ffffffc01abdbb10] do_mem_abort at ffffffc010081638
#30 [ffffffc01abdbc80] el1_ia at ffffffc010083c40
     PC: ffffffc01049c0b8  [mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+48]
     LR: ffffffc01049c0ac  [mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+36]
     SP: ffffffc01abdbc90  PSTATE: 60400005
    X29: ffffffc01abdbc90  X28: 0000000000000002  X27: 0000000000000000
    X26: ffffff802d9b8000  X25: ffffff80d67c0080  X24: ffffff802d9b8000
    X23: 0000000000000000  X22: ffffff80dba61000  X21: ffffffff016a8700
    X20: ffffff80c3e519f8  X19: 0000000000000000  X18: ffffffc017fc9038
    X17: ffffffc011d73cb0  X16: ffffffc011d73c38  X15: ffffffc011d73bc0
    X14: 000000000000003c  X13: 0000000000000078  X12: 0000000000000000
    X11: 0000000004731803  X10: ffffffc0ca9ac000   X9: ffffff802d9b8000
     X8: 0000000000000000   X7: ffffffc011d74070   X6: ffffffc011d73ff8
     X5: ffffffc011d73f80   X4: 0000000000000000   X3: ffffffc01abdbcb0
     X2: 0000000000000cc0   X1: 0000000000000000   X0: 0000000000000000
#31 [ffffffc01abdbc90] mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate at ffffffc01049c0b4
#32 [ffffffc01abdbcc0] do_anonymous_page at ffffffc010475c48
#33 [ffffffc01abdbd00] handle_pte_fault at ffffffc010475978
#34 [ffffffc01abdbdc0] handle_mm_fault at ffffffc010472d44
#35 [ffffffc01abdbe10] do_page_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8f28
#36 [ffffffc01abdbe70] do_translation_fault$4df5decbea5d08a63349aa36f07426b2 at ffffffc010fd8c84
#37 [ffffffc01abdbe80] do_mem_abort at ffffffc010081638
#38 [ffffffc01abdbff0] el0_da at ffffffc0100847c4
     PC: 70145552  LR: 701ff0b3  SP: bdad7cb0  PSTATE: 200a0030
    X12: 00000072 X11: 6fe1ffc8 X10: 0000006a  X9: ef429200
     X8: 00000000  X7: 00000040  X6: 00000008  X5: 13a45fa0
     X4: 132fcbb3  X3: 00000062  X2: 00000000  X1: 132fcb80
     X0: 13a46000
crash> struct task_struct.cgroups ffffff802d9b8000
  cgroups = 0xffffff80978a8a00
crash>
crash>
crash>
crash> struct task_struct.cgroups ffffff802d9b8000
  cgroups = 0xffffff80978a8a00
crash>
crash>
crash>
crash> dis mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate
0xffffffc01049c088 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate>:      str     x30, [x18],#8
0xffffffc01049c08c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+4>:    stp     x29, x30, [sp,#-32]!
0xffffffc01049c090 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+8>:    str     x19, [sp,#16]
0xffffffc01049c094 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+12>:   mov     x29, sp
0xffffffc01049c098 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+16>:   cbz     x0, 0xffffffc01049c160 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+216>
0xffffffc01049c09c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+20>:   tbz     w2, #6, 0xffffffc01049c160 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+216>
0xffffffc01049c0a0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+24>:   mov     w19, w1
0xffffffc01049c0a4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+28>:   bl      0xffffffc010337730 <__rcu_read_lock>
0xffffffc01049c0a8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+32>:   bl      0xffffffc0102d3b74 <kthread_blkcg>
0xffffffc01049c0ac <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+36>:   cbnz    x0, 0xffffffc01049c0c0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+56>
0xffffffc01049c0b0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+40>:   mrs     x8, sp_el0
0xffffffc01049c0b4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+44>:   ldr     x8, [x8,#2368]
0xffffffc01049c0b8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+48>:   ldr     x0, [x8,#24]
0xffffffc01049c0bc <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+52>:   cbz     x0, 0xffffffc01049c0d4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+76>
0xffffffc01049c0c0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+56>:   ldr     x8, [x0]
0xffffffc01049c0c4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+60>:   ldr     w8, [x8,#2448]
0xffffffc01049c0c8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+64>:   cbnz    w8, 0xffffffc01049c0dc <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+84>
0xffffffc01049c0cc <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+68>:   ldr     x0, [x0,#264]
0xffffffc01049c0d0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+72>:   cbnz    x0, 0xffffffc01049c0c0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+56>
0xffffffc01049c0d4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+76>:   bl      0xffffffc010337744 <__rcu_read_unlock>
0xffffffc01049c0d8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+80>:   b       0xffffffc01049c160 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+216>
0xffffffc01049c0dc <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+84>:   bl      0xffffffc010337744 <__rcu_read_unlock>
0xffffffc01049c0e0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+88>:   mrs     x8, sp_el0
0xffffffc01049c0e4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+92>:   ldr     x8, [x8,#2720]
0xffffffc01049c0e8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+96>:   cbnz    x8, 0xffffffc01049c160 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+216>
0xffffffc01049c0ec <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+100>:  adrp    x0, 0xffffffc011cd6000 <init_mm+384>
0xffffffc01049c0f0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+104>:  add     x0, x0, #0x3b8
0xffffffc01049c0f4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+108>:  bl      0xffffffc010fd6e08 <_raw_spin_lock>
0xffffffc01049c0f8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+112>:  adrp    x8, 0xffffffc011e5e000 <memblock_reserved_init_regions+3464>
0xffffffc01049c0fc <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+116>:  ldr     x9, [x8,#520]
0xffffffc01049c100 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+120>:  mov     w10, #0xffffffd8                // #-40
0xffffffc01049c104 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+124>:  mov     x11, #0xfffffffffffffe78        // #-392
0xffffffc01049c108 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+128>:  sxtw    x8, w19
0xffffffc01049c10c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+132>:  add     x9, x9, w19, sxtw #4
0xffffffc01049c110 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+136>:  smaddl  x10, w19, w10, x11
0xffffffc01049c114 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+140>:  mov     w11, #0x28                      // #40
0xffffffc01049c118 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+144>:  mov     x12, x9
0xffffffc01049c11c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+148>:  ldr     x12, [x12]
0xffffffc01049c120 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+152>:  add     x12, x12, x10
0xffffffc01049c124 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+156>:  madd    x13, x8, x11, x12
0xffffffc01049c128 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+160>:  add     x13, x13, #0x188
0xffffffc01049c12c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+164>:  cmp     x13, x9
0xffffffc01049c130 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+168>:  b.eq    0xffffffc01049c154 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+204>
0xffffffc01049c134 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+172>:  ldr     x13, [x12,#184]
0xffffffc01049c138 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+176>:  madd    x12, x8, x11, x12
0xffffffc01049c13c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+180>:  add     x12, x12, #0x188
0xffffffc01049c140 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+184>:  cbz     x13, 0xffffffc01049c11c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+148>
0xffffffc01049c144 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+188>:  ldr     x8, [x13,#160]
0xffffffc01049c148 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+192>:  mov     w1, #0x1                        // #1
0xffffffc01049c14c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+196>:  ldr     x0, [x8,#1360]
0xffffffc01049c150 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+200>:  bl      0xffffffc010760124 <blkcg_schedule_throttle>
0xffffffc01049c154 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+204>:  adrp    x0, 0xffffffc011cd6000 <init_mm+384>
0xffffffc01049c158 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+208>:  add     x0, x0, #0x3b8
0xffffffc01049c15c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+212>:  bl      0xffffffc010fd6ee0 <_raw_spin_unlock>
0xffffffc01049c160 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+216>:  ldr     x19, [sp,#16]
0xffffffc01049c164 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+220>:  ldp     x29, x30, [sp],#32
0xffffffc01049c168 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+224>:  ldr     x30, [x18,#-8]!
0xffffffc01049c16c <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+228>:  ret
crash>
crash> struct task_struct.cgroups ffffff802d9b8000
  cgroups = 0xffffff80978a8a00
crash>
crash>
```

my analysis

```
  // sp_el0 is current task TASK: ffffff802d9b800
  0xffffffc01049c0b0 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+40>:   mrs     x8, sp_el0    
  // load task_struct.cgroups   cgroups = 0xffffff80978a8a00
  0xffffffc01049c0b4 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+44>:   ldr     x8, [x8,#2368]
  // bug is here x8 now is 0
  0xffffffc01049c0b8 <mem_cgroup_throttle_swaprate+48>:   ldr     x0, [x8,#24]
```

help me , is it a CPU hardware issue or a software issue?

Comment: Looks like you have an unexpected null pointer in your task block.